# React: Create CSV at client side with data retrieved from backend via Socket IO

Tags: reactjs, csv, export-to-csv

I am looking for a solution whereby data retrieved from the backend is written to a csv and downloaded to the clients pc triggered by an event on one of my react components. I have tried a few solutions with packages such as react-csv but I cannot get the async feature to work.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "async feature" but if you are just looking to create a CSV download, you can use a simple anchor tag with the `download` attribute like so:

```
  <a
    href=`data:text/csv,${encodeURI(your-csv-string)}`
    download=`your-file.csv`>

    Click to download
  </a>
```

If you need to hook into an event within a component you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
handleClick() {
  // Do some stuff (build the csv string?)

  // Initiate the download
  this.link.href = `data:text/csv,${encodeURI(your-csv-string)}`
  this.link.download = `your-file.csv`
  this.link.click()
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      // Create a hidden link with a ref you can use later
      <a ref={link => this.link = link}
        style={{display: 'none'}}
      />

      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to download</button>
    </div>
  )  
}
```